# Why is my XPath using following-sibling not working?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath, web-scraping

I need to select the next input field and the `A` field, following the active page `(class="active_page")` on the two sample HTML code below, but the following two XPath are not working.

How would I accomplish the `following-sibling` and what is the easiest way of doing this?

```
//*[@id="pagination"]/ul/li[2]/a/following-sibling::A[1]

<div id="pagination">
   <ul class="zPagination">
      <li><a href="https://www.test.com/page&pagination=10">«</a></li>
      <li><a class="active_page" href="https://www.test.com/page&pagination=10">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.test.com/page&pagination=10">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.test.com/page&pagination=10">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.test.com/page&pagination=10">»</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
//TABLE[@class='table-striped']/TBODY[1]/TR[1]/TD[1]/INPUT[1]/following-sibling::INPUT[1]

<table class="table-striped">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><input id="selection" style="width: 20px;" name="test" class="zeroborder" value="001" type="radio"> </td>
         <td>S</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input id="selection" style="width: 20px;" name="test" class="zeroborder" value="002" type="radio"> </td>
         <td>S</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input id="selection" style="width: 20px;" name="test" class="zeroborder" value="003" type="radio"> </td>
         <td>S</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) two errors with your XPaths:

1. XPath and XML are case sensitive.
2. There are no `following-siblings` `a` or `input` elements.  Perhaps 
   you meant just `following`.

Comment: PHP's implementation of XPath is not case sensitive, while C#'s implementation is case sensitive, so i know that implementations differ, but what does the actual specs say?

Comment: @hanshenrik: The XML definition of [***match***](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-terminology) explicitly states that *no case folding is performed.*

Comment: @hanshenrik: Do you have a reference or other proof that XML match in XPath is case insensitive in PHP?

Comment: @kjhughes: both of the above xpath are working now using `following` instead of `following-sibling`. Thank you.